# Two Groups Ranking Acts Puzzle

Tags: probability

There are 15 acts named A, B, ..., M, N, O.

Group A ranks these acts in exact order, A is first and receives 15 points, B is second and receives 14 points, ... and lastly O is last receiving just 1 point.

Group B then ranks these acts in whatever order they wish, giving their top act 15 points, their second act 14 points, etc, and their last act 1 point.

Then the scores of Group A and Group B are added together and the final ranks are revealed. Ties are resolved depending on the act's position in Group B's ranking. Eg if act D and E received the same combined score, but act E scored more points in Group B's rankings, then act E will be placed above rank D in the final rankings.

There are clearly 15! possible ranking permutations for Group B. How many of those permutations would place act A in last place in the final combined rankings? How many of those permutations would place act A in second-from-last place in the final combined rankings?

Comment: what have you tried? did you find at least one solution to get A to the last place?

Comment: Yes, the obvious solution to get A in last place is the exact reversal of Group A's ranks. I believe this is the only solution for that. The second from last place is a little trickier.